# pros and cons of db and ndb in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, storage, google-cloud-datastore

I have seen a little of this in stack overflow but I am wondering if there is any reason to use the DB entity model and what the specific pros and cons of using on or the other are.

I have read the ndb is a little faster and that it helps with caching.  They have a good bit of info in the docs but don't really straight out say that ndb is better.  At least I haven't found that yet.

Comment: this video explain very well the ndb features http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZsxWn58pS0

Comment: We *should* say that NDB is better because that's what we believe. We just have been slow in finding the time to update the docs.

Comment: The biggest problem I have with GAE and other many other Google Cloud products I have tried is demonstrated by Guido statement. The docs are a mess and confusing. I read one thing and land up clicking so many links I do not remember where I started and there are so many experimental and out of date docs. Google needs to take a look at AWS documentation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As far as I can tell ndb is an evolution of db, kept seperate to maintain compatability.

Have a look at the cheat sheet, it details the main differences

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic

But it does not mention the other features such as computed properties.

If you are starting a new project I see no reason not to use ndb and every reason to.

EDIT: Alt link for document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit#