# Google App Engine Datastore get value of property

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have some questions. Suppose we have this Model for Datastore:

```
class SessionID(db.Model):
    SESSIONID = db.StringProperty()
    userid = db.StringProperty()
    userip = db.StringProperty()
    exp_time = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Lets say we registered the SESSIONID property to 1234, assigned userid to bob, the userip to 123.123.123.123, and the exp_time to 1

**Question 1:**
Suppose we know the SESSIONID value. Using that value, how can I get the value of userid?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question which I answered? Are you going to post a question every time you need to make a query against your datastore?

Comment: No, I have tried to get the value of userid by using `uss = SessionID.all().filter('SESSIONID =', sid).get()
            if uss:
                usid = str(uss.userid)`, but It will return a blank.

Comment: maybe because there is no data with that sid in datastore

Comment: Nope. The data was able to be viewed using the datastore viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from models import User 
# Assuming you have user model class in models
user = User.query().filter(User.SESSIONID==1234).get()
```

Now user will contain object or objects(depending on uniqueness of SESSIONID)  of User class, so to get userid just do:

```
id = user.userid
```

Hope it helps.

PS: Read the documentation mentioned by Daniel, that will help you a lot.

Comment: Umm. `type object 'SessionID' has no attribute 'query'` Getting this error.

Comment: That is because you are using old database model. I assume you are starting up with google app engine. I would suggest start using new database (i.e. ndb). For now use:

    user = User.all().filter(SESSIONID=='1234').get()
    id = user.userid

Comment: Let us know if you find any further difficulty.

Comment: Why do I need to use the new "ndb" instead of the old db?

Comment: That's very much a theoretical question, just google it and you will find yourself. To begin with have a look into this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852442/pros-and-cons-of-db-and-ndb-in-google-app-engine